# print two tables

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a jpanel that contains two tables , but the problem that the width of the tables is larger than tha page which tables appear on. Is there away to make tables fit with page width , or should i sesize the tables themselves ??

here is what i did :

```
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
 job.setJobName("test");

 job.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
        @Override
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) throws PrinterException{
        if (pageNum > 0){
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }


        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        jPanel1.print(g2);

         // jTable1.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
 });
 boolean ok = job.printDialog();
 if (ok) {
     try {
          job.print();
     } catch (PrinterException ex) {

     }
 }
```

Comment: One solution is to use a reporting utility as usually it's easier to create printer output outputs this way, and they usually look much nicer since this is precisely what they're built to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what do you mean by using reporting utility???
do mean using jasper report???

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I don't think that Swing components are built to print cleanly or easily but rather are built best for displaying data on a screen. This shows in your example above, in how you have to jump through many hoops to try to get your data to print cleanly with Swing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried using jasper reports, but unfortunately the same problem arised which is i couldn't print two tables on the same report